# Populate User lookup field by trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, lookup, map

I have a need to populate a lookup field on a custom object with a partner user. The only problem is that I need this to be populated with the partner user who is set up as a contact under the account that is related to the custom object through a two lookup relationships.

Here is the structure:

Receiving__c: (Custom Object) I'm trying to populate a "Receiver_Contact__c" field with the partner user. I have a formula that populates the Account ID of the Partner User's Account and that is the "Receiver_Account_Number__c" field.

I basically want run a query and return user's where their "contact.AccountId" value matches "Receiver_Account_Number__c" field on my "Receiving__c" object and then set that User Id to my "Receiver_Contact__c" field on that same object.

My code is below, any help is greatly appreciated, as always!

```
   trigger getReceiverUser on Receiving__c (before insert, before update){

  //get the acct Id and store it in a set.
    set<Id> acctIdSet = new set<Id>();
    for(Receiving__c rec: trigger.new){
        if(rec.Receiver_Account_Number__c  != null){
            acctIdSet.add(rec.Receiver_Account_Number__c);
        }
    }

    //query the user records and get the associated accounts.
    map<id, User> usrMap = new map<id, User>([SELECT id, contact.accountid from user where contact.accountid IN: acctIdSet]);

    //update the Receiving value based on the account id in the record.
    for(Receiving__c rec: trigger.new){
        if(usrMap.containsKey(rec.Receiver_Account_Number__c)){
            rec.Receiver_Contact__c  = usrMap.get(rec.Receiver_Account_Number__c).contact.accountid;
        }       
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you we're on the right track, although when you have this line

```
usrMap.containsKey(rec.Receiver_Account_Number__c)
```

You are actually saying: Return true or false if the `Id` of the User will equal the `Receiver_Account_Number__c field` which will always be false.

Also I checked and there is an actual field in the User table that is called `AccountId`. It might be easier to use that instead of `contact.AccountId`. Let me know if you have a problem with that.

Third point which is more of a suggestion you can narrow the SOQL query event more by adding another filter to the where clause to check if the User has the Partner licence type or a specific profile for this kind of user. You can improve the SOQL query even more by adding the filter `isActive = true` to make sure you don't select any inactive users

```
        trigger getReceiverUser on Receiving__c (before insert, before update){

            //get the acct Id and store it in a set.
            set<Id> acctIdSet = new set<Id>();
            Map<Id,Receiving__c> recMap = new Map<Id, Receiving__c>();
            for(Receiving__c rec: trigger.new){
                if(rec.Receiver_Account_Number__c  != null){
                    acctIdSet.add(rec.Receiver_Account_Number_c);
                    recMap.put(rec.Receiver_Account_Number_c, rec)
                }
            }

            //query the user records and get the associated accounts.
            List<User> usrList = new List<User>([SELECT id, AccountId from user where AccountId IN: acctIdSet]);

            for(User usr : usrList){
                if(recMap.containsKey(usr.AccountId)){
                    recMap.get(usr.AccountId).Receiver_Contact__c = usr.Id;
                }
            }

        }
```

You could also get rid of the if clause in the second for loop that checks if it contains a key as you already make sure in the SOQL query to only retrieve Users where the AccountId matches.

Hope it helps

Comment: That worked like a charm, thank you for the help Mihai! Much appreciated.

Comment: Glad I could help.